# ValueError on executing my docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, valueerror

the way for employment, I've been studying docker. I built container from `dockerfile`, and got `ValueError` when I run a container message says I wrote wrong urls, but I have no idea how could I fix.

I got this message from log:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/echo/docker_test.py", line 6, in <module>
>    def hello():
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1315, in decorator
>    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
>    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1275, in add_url_rule
>    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 666, in __init__
>    raise ValueError("urls must start with a leading slash")
> ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash
> ```

And this is my docker_test.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hi/')
def hi():
    mth=request.method
    print("hello world")
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
'''
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN pip install flask
RUN mkdir /echo
COPY docker_test.py /echo

CMD ["python", "/echo/docker_test.py"]
```

and my development environment:
docker : 20.10.2
python : 3.9

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code sample (one has a function named `hello` and one `hi`).  Can you double-check that you've included the correct code in the question and that you've re-run `docker build` if needed?

Comment: No double checking required, this is obviously not the actual code OP is running. The `<br>` all over the place would cause a variety of errors, starting with the fact that there's probably no docker image called `python:3.9<br>`. OP, please read the help pages on question formatting and edit your question to include your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

You posted different code then you build into docker:

In the error you have:

```
def hello():
```

But your code looks like:

```
@app.route('/hi/')
def hi():
```

So probably before you had sth like this:

```
@app.route('hi/')
def hello():
```

And error is caused by missing shash on the beginning of the route url:

```
@app.route('hi/')
```

Should be

```
@app.route('/hi/')
```

### Solution

Build docker image again:

```
build docker . -t python_app:latest

docker run -p 5000:5000 python_app:latest
```

Then everything should be fine.

Comment: The `<br>` is obviously not in the code because otherwise the python exception would be a SyntaxError. OP provably just messed up the code formatting.

Comment: Ahh sure. Let me fix that answer :)